# Can't push object into an array which is inside another array

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to push data into the 'workout' sub sub array.

My 'Workout' DB

```
    { 
     "_id" : "LpM8ubqJNKwgcDuKC",
     "userID" : "yZTaeqJ8iNGkvs3MS",
     "workouts" : [ 
        { "_id" : "fiaMqNRucPq4SSXCi", 
          "scheculedFor" : ISODate("2016-08-23T11:17:55.428Z"), 
          "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-23T11:17:55.428Z"), 
          "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-23T11:17:55.428Z"), 
          "started" : true, 
          "finished" : false,
          "type" : false,
          "workout" : [ ]
         }  
                 ], 
     "training" : true 
    }
```

And my query

```
Workout.update({ 
       '_id':"LpM8ubqJNKwgcDuKC"
       'workouts._id':"fiaMqNRucPq4SSXCi"
        },
        { $push: {
            'workouts.$.workout.0':{name:"Test"}}
        }
    );
```

I have tried many variations of the query and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need not use `.0` in your update query.

Try the below query

```
Workout.update({ 
   '_id':"LpM8ubqJNKwgcDuKC"
   'workouts._id':"fiaMqNRucPq4SSXCi"
    },
    { $push: {
        'workouts.$.workout':{name:"Test"}}
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, i need 15 rep to do that. But when i have enough i will do so :)